# Gitlab API endpoint to find all issues that contains a specific label

Tags: gitlab-api

I am triying to retrieve all issues in a Gitlab instance that contains a specific label. I only able to retrieve those issues that have only one label but my issues have two or three labels more.

Have anybody found a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

At the top of the [Issues API page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#list-issues), it shows various ways to list a Project's Issues, including a way to use multiple labels:
`GET /issues?labels=foo,bar`

An issue does have to have all the labels you query to be returned, but you should be able to get all issues with a set of labels with multiple queries.